# Swift - image assets

Tags: git

I pulled code from a common git where my colleague had pushed. He added an image to the image assets. But that image is not appearing in my local copy. This has been an intermittent problem.  How can we correct this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the image that he added is **not** in the same directory (or it's subdirectory) as your other project files. So when he adds and commits code on git then only the files in the xcode project directory and it's subdirectories are committed and pushed.

To fix this, simply copy your image files in xcode projects directory and then add them to xcode images.xcassets.

If it still doesn't work then check the .gitignore file in the projects directory and see if it ignores .jpg or .png files.

Comment: thanks for the response. I opened terminal in my colleague system and went to the location where his xcode project lies. Used this command 'git status'. It showed the untracked files(here all images are untracked). Then I used 'git add .' command. Pulled and pushed then I pulled and pushed in my system. This works fine. Thanks again.